# Good way to use word similarity as a feature in supervised ML on text

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language, text-mining, feature-engineering

I have a pretty low N data set of small sentences tagged with a label. I would like to create a classifier on this dataset. The word choice is not very variable since the domain is pretty specific. Nonetheless, it can happen that words are misspelled or (rarer) variants that are not caught by lemmatization and stemming engines.

What are the best practices in the field to take these factors in account?

Answer (score 0):

Learning your model should rely on generalization, to generalize data you need unification. If you can't stem or lemm maybe you can use Levenshtein to find nearest stem or w2v term? If you don't provide information about semantic similarity between words but noised by misspelling you could expect that your model would be much worst than model with that information. Without seeing data is hard to say what would be the best option for denoise data. However it's very important to not skip a denoising step.